# windows like (context menu) unzipper in mac?

Tags: software-recommendation, finder, switching, zip, archive

Is there an app that acts like windows-based unzipper?

I don't want my unarchiver unzip when I click a zipped file. I rather want to right click then click 'unzip' or something similar.

**Update**: I think people are getting confused. I know that I can unzip a file simply by double clicking it. I DON'T WANT THAT. I like to have a context menu like windows application. Is this possible?

Comment: You know you just double click a zip file on a mac to unzip it right… it's built in

Comment: What do you want the context menu to do that double-clicking does not?

Comment: You don't say why you can't just double click on it. Why make it harder?

Comment: Then, what would you like to be done when the archive is double–clicked?

Comment: @vocaro // I don't want anything when I double click it

Comment: @JasonSalaz // I'm just researching out of curiosity

Comment: "I don't want anything when I double click it"... Double-clicking a file will open the app it's assigned to. There's no way to prevent that. If you want a different app to open, select the file and then choose File > Get Info and change the Open With setting.

Comment: why do people responding to questions about OSX always insist on asking *"why do you need Y method when you can do it already by X method"*. The OP is asking if there is a program that comes with a contextual menu. **He is NOT asking HOW TO UNZIP files**. I'm also after a archive utility that contains contextual menues. If you have ever used winRAR on a windows machine you will see there are many features that the built in OSX util is missing. eg. you cant extract split archives, and you cant extract multiple archives to a single folder.

Comment: @OrangeBox and others, best to start a new question explaining exactly what contextual menu function you wish to discuss / find a solution to.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unarchiving is built into OS X. All you have to do to unarchive a file is to open it. You can do that by double clicking, pressing <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> (between i and p), or by right-clicking and choosing Open.

[image]

So, just right-click on the file and select Open to unarchive. Ta-da, no extra software required.

Answer (score 2):

You can make an automator service that sends the selected file to Archive Utility.app (found in /System/CoreServices) and make it into a contextual menu item

Answer (score 1):

**No,** there is nothing like that on the Mac platform that I am aware of.

I believe what Moon is going on about is that in the Windows Explorer, it's possible to do more with .zip archives than what the Mac Finder lets you do. In the Windows Explorer you can use a contextual menu command to inspect an archive with multiple items inside and see those items listed before you decide whether you want to extract anything or not. You can extract only certain items within an archive without extracting the entire archive. No, there's no way to get that kind of flexibility in the Mac Finder.

Using the contextual menu in the Finder on Mac OS X, you can either extract the entire contents of a .zip file, or nothing.

Comment: Technically you can 'peek' at what files are within an archive using [BetterZip](http://macitbetter.com), and choose to extract selected files from it. It is not native to OS X but still handy to know